# Filter array based of two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, lodash

i've the following array of object, (ets say that the timestemp here is mock and greater is the last one)

```
var firstArr = [{
  id: 1,
  a: 2,
  timestemp: 111
}, {
  id: 2,
  a: 4,
  timestemp: 222
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 6,
  timestemp: 333
}, {
  id: 1,
  a: 3,
  timestemp: 777
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 5555,
  timestemp: 5555
}];
```

What I need to do is somehow filter this array and create new array with unique value.

I need at the end

```
var endArr = [{
  id: 1,
  a: 3,
  timestemp: 777
}, {
  id: 2,
  a: 4,
  timestemp: 222
},  {
  id: 3,
  a: 5555,
  timestemp: 555
}];
```

As you can see I've filter this array by two things

> 1. uniqe ID (the entry 1 & 3 are exist just once)
> 2. timestemp (add just the object with the last timestemp)

How can I do that with array methods such as map/reduce/filter?

I try to do it with array.filter without success

Comment: "*I try to do it with array.filter without success*" - so show us that failed attempt, tell us how it went wrong, tell us of any errors that were generated (visible in the developer console, F12 in most browsers), explain what it did and what you wanted it to do instead. This way you might learn something useful for next time, and others might learn something important, or interesting, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [orderBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) and [uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) to get all items with unique ids that has the latest timestamps:

```js
var firstArr = [{
  id: 1,
  a: 2,
  timestamp: 111
}, {
  id: 2,
  a: 4,
  timestamp: 222
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 6,
  timestamp: 333
}, {
  id: 1,
  a: 3,
  timestamp: 777
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 5555,
  timestamp: 5555
}];

var result = _(firstArr)
.orderBy(['id', 'timestamp'], ['asc', 'desc'])
.uniqBy('id')
.value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you spelt timestamp as timestemp.

```
var firstArr = [{
  id: 1,
  a: 2,
  timestamp: 111
}, {
  id: 2,
  a: 4,
  timestamp: 222
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 6,
  timestamp: 333
}, {
  id: 1,
  a: 3,
  timestamp: 777
}, {
  id: 3,
  a: 5555,
  timestamp: 5555
}];
```

Here is the function:

```
function updateList(a_list) {

    var seen = {};

    for (var entry in a_list) {
        var id = a_list[entry]["id"];

        if (seen.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            var current_timestamp = seen[id]["timestamp"]
            var check_timestamp = a_list[entry]["timestamp"]

            if (current_timestamp < check_timestamp) {
                 seen[id] = a_list[entry];
            }

        } else {
            seen[id] = a_list[entry];
        }
    }

    var updated = [];
    for (var newest in seen) {
        updated.push(seen[newest]);
    } 
    return updated;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vpg3onqm/
If this is the answer you want, make sure to press upvote and the greentick.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the requirement of using `filter`/`map`/`reduce`, I think I'd go with:

```
var lastestPerId = firstArr.reduce(function(state, curr) {
  if(state[curr.id]){ // We've seen this id before
     if(curr.timestemp > state[curr.id].timestemp) { // and its later
        state[curr.id] = curr; // so, update this item to be the latest item
     }
  } else {
     state[curr.id]  = curr; // add because unknown
  }

  return state; // pass along the state to the next item in the array
}, {});

var endArr = Object.keys(lastestPerId)
    .map(function (key) {return bestPerId[key]});
```

This creates an initial state (`{}`), loops over each item in `firstArr`. It tries to find out if the `id` is already known, and if it is it keeps track (in `state`) of the item with the highest `timestemp`. The `state` is passed along for each element in `firstArr`. Because the result is an object (with `id`'s as keys, and the actual item as value), we need to `map` it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if `firstArr` is sorted by timestamp. The returned array will also be sorted by timestamp.

Starting from the end of the array (larger timestamps), include the current element in the new array if it was not already found. `found` array is used to keep track of extracted elements.

```
var found = [];
firstArr.reverse().filter( function(el){

  if( found.indexOf( el.id ) === -1 ){
    found.push( el.id );
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}).reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

groupBy is your friend: https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

```
_(firstArr)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map(function(x) {
    return _(x).orderBy(x,['timestemp'], ['desc']).head();
  })
  .value();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/53esaqLz/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and then filter first id occurrence:

```js
var firstArr = [
    { id: 1, a: 2, timestemp: 111 },
    { id: 2, a: 4, timestemp: 222 },
    { id: 3, a: 6, timestemp: 333 },
    { id: 1, a: 3, timestemp: 777 },
    { id: 3, a: 5555, timestemp: 5555 }
];

// sort firstArr by decrescent timestamp:
firstArr.sort((x,y)=>y.timestemp-x.timestemp);

// get only the first occurrence of each id:
var endArr = firstArr.filter((o,i)=>i==firstArr.findIndex(u=>u.id==o.id));

// job finished
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( endArr, null, 2 );
```

```html
<pre id=output>
```